# Get List of available screen resolutions vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming a 2d game using vb.net and I want to get all available resolutions of the user's screen.

Please I want all answers in **vb.net**

any helps will be appreciated

Comment: If you do a quick research, you would see that you have to rely on a WinAPI call and iterate through all the returned results. Also you would notice that there are various codes done in C# but not too many in VB.NET (although I found one in VB, which is basically the same). I guess that this is a good enough answer for a so wide question. You cannot expect to get here a full working code (built from scratch or converted from C#). Please, work a bit by your own and come back here with a more specific problem.

Comment: we used this program QRes. you can process-start it with proper arguments and it will dump all modes on stdout. you could consume the output in language of your choice, not only vb-net. moreover it could change resolutions too.

Comment: in fact I did search for hours with no answer in vb.net
all what I have found in c#
that made me ask this question , and if you have any code in vb.net please just give it to me , and thank you soo much

Comment: and I can change resolution , I have a module which do this :D